# Update Conact or Group_Concat by joining two tables

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have an unusual need for a table structure. Caveat beforehand given prior objections is this is a very simple example of an in fact much more complex table and problem, one that does not lend itself to normal query/normalization. So I am not asking this question as a newbie who doesn't 'get' that the answer is normalized data, I'm asking as a somewhat experienced developer whose best solution for this application is to store field values into a text delimited field. If you have objections to that feel free to not answer :)

Basically I have two tables, one that I have already stored a field with delimited values from another standard/normalized table:

[image]

Products Field is delimited field that was derived from a standard Store/Branch/Products table (again these are just simple field/table examples of a much more complex problem).

I then have a normalized table with "Store" and "Product":

[image]

And I need to now use the second table to update the first table with the Products from it's store that it does not have:
[image]

As an FYI I used Group_Concat to create the first Text Delimited Field (Products) and thought there might be a way to do a Join with Group_Concat.

Again i totally understand that I could achieve this with a simpler Store/Product Table and a Store/Location/Product table w/o text delimited fields which appear to defeat the very purpose of RDBMS; in my scenario it is the most efficient solution to allow for dynamic queries I require.

Comment: Your delimiters are quite a mess. This is not about SQL but string manipulation. You may want to extract all that data and put the values in a properly structured table with well defined columns/fields. There is no easy solution to this, and as I said, you need to first define the rules of those messy delimiters.

Comment: Yes, the right answer, as annoying as it sounds, is to normalize your data. There are very rare situations where you actually want to store delimited data in the database. The database already has mechanisms for storing lists of things: tables. You will want to introduce new tables to store lists of items carried/not carried.

Comment: @RicardoC. I get that you don't normally want to store delimited data and my data IS in fact currently normalzed. However for a specific purpose I need to extract data into a delimited text field. Explaning the larger problem is beyond the scope of this Q or Stack even but my only solution to my larger problem currently is to store a delimited text field.I have been down every other path query/data wise and I ended up where I am; having to store a delimted text field and needing to use that to extract/store another.

Comment: @user3649739 I understand that your need as end result is the concatenated string, my issue is not about producing the output, but about using such ugly thing as input. If you have it normalized somewhere else, then let us use THAT as the input. That aside, the question of what are the meaning of those bars and commas remains. You have not stated the logic or meaning of "items NOT found in", how you define found Vs not-found? You need to: 1) split the string 2) normalize 3) compare 4) concatenate.

Comment: @user3649739 I see that you have strings within strings! >.< ok, split by bar | save in temp table, then split by comma and save in another temp table, then go to town on working the select query then concatenate again.

Comment: How to split strings: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/04/21/sql-server-split-comma-separated-list-without-using-a-function/ and http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: @Ricardo Oh let me clarify something here my bad; I used the pipes simply to indicate fields e.g FieldA | FieldB | FIeldC. That is how I notate for my own use internally so my apologies if that confused things. Basically I have normal fields with a varchar and then one field with comma delimited text.

Comment: @Ricardo I will try to make a SqlFiddle from this to make it clearer. In the interim, in the example above the first record would look into the second table for all records with "McDonalds" and fine all values NOT in the string delimited field and concatenate those, thus it would find 'Pomme Frites" and "Royale with Cheese" and group concatenate those into a new field as 'Royal with Cheeese','Pomme Frittes'.  SqlFiddle to follow

Comment: I can't think how you got to such a bad place. If you're not going to bother with the efficiencies that an RDBMS affords then there's probably little point using one.

Comment: @Strawberry I am not in a mess. I have a table I needed to gather a list of values into and now need to grab "not" values. I get what the RDBMS is for and how to normalize/query table. Due to the ad hoc query I find mysef required to allow, this is the most efficient way to deliver the information. If you can't think of a solution that is fine but your reply becomes less than useful.

Comment: @Ricardo, I updated with Screenshots since SqlFidllde would not let me create two tables to demo wtih. I hope this clarified.

Comment: OK, let's assume you've hit upon the one (and only) situation in the entire (brief) history of RDBMS development that requires a denormalized approach. What determines the order in which values appear in the products table?

Comment: @Strawberry Horatio, Horatio,,,